# Duplicate Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) in different CloudFront Distributions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

What I want:

I want to set up a staging environment for new features. I would like to direct 10% of production request to another version of the script.

What I tried

I've tried setting up another S3 bucket with static webiste + cloudfront with different alternative domain name (e.g. app-beta.example.org).

I need to use a different alternative subdomain because Cloudfront does not allow same alternative domain name with multiple distributions.

In Route 53, I set up alias A records like this:

- `app-beta.example.org` => `Alias Cloudfont Distribution (s3://app-beta.example.org)`
- `app.example.org` => `Alias app-beta.example.org (weighted 10)`
- `app.example.org` => `Alias Cloudfont Distribution (s3://app.example.org) (weighted 100)`

I am getting error
 `com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.CNAMEAlreadyExistsException: One or more of the CNAMEs you provided are already associated with a different resource. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 409; Error Code: CNAMEAlreadyExists; Request ID: 8de92645-a437-48b4-a74e-bac9ed853ca2; Proxy: null)`

Iam using weighted route policy and using same Domain names.

How can we use lambda edge in this scenario if above is not achieved directly

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? This appears to be related to creating a CloudFront distribution not adding a roue 53 record :)

Answer (score 0):

This upon research, I figured out that the CNAME or DOmain name that we use accross cloudfront are global and you can't have two distributions to use 1 domain name.